# Linux: Join two lines with an equal value in the SAME file

Tags: linux, join, merge

I have a file that looks like this:

1 51 Brahui A C A A T
1 51 Brahui A C A G T
3 51 Brahui A C A G C
3 51 Brahui A C G A T
5 51 Brahui A C G A T
5 51 Brahui A C G G C
7 51 Brahui A C G A T
7 51 Brahui A C G G T
9 51 Brahui A C G G T
9 51 Brahui A C G G T

And I want to generate an output file whereby if the first column/field are of equal value then I want to merge the two lines together with a "/" character as a delimiter. For example:

1 51 Brahui A/A C/C A/A A/G T/T
3 51 Brahui A/A C/C A/G G/A C/T

Is there a way that I can do that?

P.S.The columns starting from $4 are actually 2,834 long (i.e. $4-$2841) so I don't think it will be practical to physically enter $4, $5, $6, etc.. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: i was hoping I would be able to do this using just the shell terminal in Linux. But I can also us Perl

Answer (score 0):

```
pearl.229>awk '{a=$1;
          b=$4;
          c=$5;
          d=$6;
          e=$7;
          f=$8;
          getline;
          if(a==$1)
          print a,$2,$3,b"/"$4,c"/"$5,d"/"$6,e"/"$7,f"/"$8}' file3
    1 51 Brahui A/A C/C A/A A/G T/T
    3 51 Brahui A/A C/C A/G G/A C/T
    5 51 Brahui A/A C/C G/G A/G T/C
    7 51 Brahui A/A C/C G/G A/G T/T
    9 51 Brahui A/A C/C G/G G/G T/T
    pearl.230>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using fmt.  It makes the code prettier.

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat doit 
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  fmt="%s %s %s %s/%s %s/%s %s/%s %s/%s %s/%s\n";
}

one == $1 {
  split(last,a);
  printf(fmt, $1,$2,$3, a[4],$4, a[5],$5, a[6],$6, a[7],$7, a[8],$8);
}

{ last = $0; one = $1; }

[ghoti@pc ~]$ ./doit input.txt 
1 51 Brahui A/A C/C A/A A/G T/T
3 51 Brahui A/A C/C A/G G/A C/T
5 51 Brahui A/A C/C G/G A/G T/C
7 51 Brahui A/A C/C G/G A/G T/T
9 51 Brahui A/A C/C G/G G/G T/T
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```